# Traduction du mot « turned » en français (changement de camp)

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Je n'arrive pas à trouver une bonne traduction pour le mot « turned » dans la phrase suivante :

> They know a criminal turned informant.

J'ai essayé :

> Ils connaissent un criminel qui est devenu informateur.

Je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit une bonne traduction ou qu'elle exprime le sens voulu.

La phrase vient d'un reportage d'actualité. L'homme était criminel, mais maintenant il est informateur. Il est encore criminel, mais il donne aussi des informations à la police pour ses propres bénéfices.

(On utilise aussi le mot « turned » pour parler de l'espionnage.)

Comment: Je ne vois pas ce que l'espionage ou la justice ont de si particulier dans ce contexte.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Perhaps not in particular. It is just usually the context in which it is used in English. I am not sure if the same is true of French. I was simply trying to give some context of my meaning.

Comment: Ok I see. You are specifically interested in this “changing sides” connotation.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edit of clarification.

Answer (score 6):

« Qui est devenu informateur » est correct, mais pas forcément la meilleure traduction. *Devenir* est générique, il n'a pas le sens de passage du côté opposé que suggère *turned*. Je préfère :

> Ils connaissent un criminel qui est passé informateur.

On peut aussi dire que l'informateur est un criminel réformé (un criminel réformé, c'est quelqu'un qui était autrefois criminel et qui maintenant a décidé de respecter la loi).

Sans complément, on peut dire « retourner ».

> Les Bordures ont retourné l'espion syldave.
>   C'est un ancien criminel, il a été retourné.

Mais cela ne permet pas de placer le mot « informateur ». Un criminel retourné pourrait être devenu informateur.

Comment: Il me semble que « passé » marche bien ici, mais c'est une traduction vraiment difficile. Il y a certaines restrictions pour la traduction, alors je dois essayer de garder la structure de le phrase. Le problème est que « retourner » me semble très bien aussi.  J'aimerais trouver un mot qui a le sens de « retourner », mais qui peut également accepter un complément.

Comment: Retourné ?? Où as-tu lu ça ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ben, c'est du français parfaitement courant. [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retourner) I.A.2.c.

Comment: Être criminel, à la base, ce n'est pas une opinion ou un camp. Employer cette expression devient vraiment tiré par les cheveux de mon point de vue. Je n'aurais probablement pas compris. Note que même dans des cas typiques comme le deuxième exemple cité, l'auteur utilise des guillemets. La formulation à la voie active que tu proposes me parait étrange, une utilisation moins directe de ce *retourner* (quelqu'un contre son camp) m'aurait convenu mais seulement dans le cas de l'espion, pas d'un criminel quelconque.

Comment: Mon professeur de traduction préfère 'est devenu'. Il m'a dit que 'passé' est acceptable, mais n'est pas la meilleure traduction.

Answer (score 1):

En français la phrase pour dire cela serait probablement strucutrée différement.

L'adjectif "repenti" me semble parfait recouvrir le cas d'un malfrat devenu informateur.
C'est le terme utilisé par exemple dans le cas des anciens mafieux qui collaborent avec la police.

> Les forces de l'ordre ont été renseignées par un ancien criminel repenti.
>
> La police travaille avec un ancien délinquant devenu indic/informateur

Concernant le terme *retourné*, il me semble plus spécifique au monde de l'espionage. Je ne me rappelle pas l'avoir entendu à propos d'affaires criminelles ordinaires.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense qu'il faut oublier la structure de la phrase initiale, sans en oublier l'idée. Par ailleurs, en français, on a le mot *indic*, moins formel que *informateur*, mais qui déjà contient l'idée d'ancien criminel. Pourquoi ne pas l'utiliser? Mais en gardant le mot *informateur* on pourrait dire:

- "Ils utilisent les services d'un criminel qui leur sert d'informateur"

Avec cette proposition, j'utilise surtout le contexte donné. Sinon, il serait difficile d'arriver à véhiculer tout le sens de la phrase, dans son contexte.

Comment: Vous avez dit : « Je pense qu'il faut oublié la structure de la phrase initiale. »  On ne peut pas. Le monde de traduction est très précis... par conséquent, on ne peut pas. En tout cas, je vous remercie pour votre réponse.

Comment: Au contraire on peut. En disant qu'il faut parfois oublier la structure initiale, je veux dire qu'on ne peut pas tout traduire mot pour mot. Il faut garder une "situation image" et tenter de transformer/traduire l'anglais en du bon français. Par exemple: _I walked back_ On ne pourra pas dire "j'ai marché en arrière" mais "je suis revenu en arrière" ou "je suis revenu sur mes pas". Ou encore dans _This man has been very much talked about_ on ne peut pas garder la structure de phrase initiale. On traduira par "on a beaucoup parlé de cet homme".